# Тестовое задание SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL Oracle

Есть таблица с исходными данными в виде:

| user_id | user_position | date_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2019 |
| 1 | 1 | 02.01.2019 |
| 1 | 2 | 03.01.2019 |
| 1 | 2 | 04.01.2019 |
| 1 | 1 | 05.01.2019 |
| 1 | 1 | 06.01.2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 01.01.2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 02.01.2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 03.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 04.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 05.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 08.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 10.01.2019 |

user_id – идентификатор сотрудника;
user_position - идентификатор присутствия (1 = присутствовал, 2 = отсутствовал)
date_position - календарная дата

Необходимо вычислить непрерывный период (по date_position), как дату начала вхождения в позицию position_start и дату окончания вхождения в позицию position_end в рабочий день по каждому сотруднику и в разрезе user_position.

Период нахождения сотрудника в позиции считается непрерывным периодом, если увеличение дат позиции date_position  на один день проходит без смены позиции и не имеются разрывы дат date_position(не рабочие дни)

Сотрудник не может занимать две позиции в один день(базовое условие уникальности данных в таблице users_position)

Результат отсортировать по сотруднику и дате начала вхождения в непрерывный период и предоставить в виде:

| user_id | user_position | position_start | position_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2019 | 02.01.2019 |
| 1 | 2 | 03.01.2019 | 03.01.2019 |
| 1 | 1 | 05.01.2019 | 06.01.2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 01.01.2019 | 03.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 04.01.2019 | 05.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 08.01.2019 | 08.01.2019 |
| 2 | 2 | 10.01.2019 | 10.01.2019 |

Пытаюсь использовать следующее:

```
SELECT user_id, user_position, MIN (date_position) dt_open, MAX (date_position) dt_close
FROM (
    SELECT tt.*, SUM (chng) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, user_position ORDER BY date_position ASC) rnk
    FROM (
        SELECT users_position.*,
            CASE 
            WHEN COALESCE (
                LAG (MAX (date_position)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, user_position ORDER BY date_position ASC),
                date_position - 1) = (date_position - 1) THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 END chng
        FROM users_position
    ) tt
) tt
GROUP BY user_id, user_position, rnk
ORDER BY user_position, dt_open
```

Но Oracle SQL Developer выдаёт ошибку:

ORA-00937: групповая функция не является одногруппной
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 31

Comment: Подскажите возможные способы решения задачи, пожалуйста. Или помогите отредактировать мой код. Конструктивная критика приветствуется.

Comment: Вот это поясните, пожалуйста: `LAG (MAX (date_position)) OVER ( ...`, что тут вы пытаетесь получить?

Comment: Это условие, по которому непрерывный период прекращается

Comment: Это не условие, это аналитическая функция, которая что-то возвращает. Что? И как вы поняли сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: `CASE WHEN COALESCE (
   LAG (MAX (date_position)) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, user_position ORDER BY date_position ASC),   
 date_position - 1) = (date_position - 1) THEN 0  ELSE 1 END `  Должно возвращать все поля users_position плюс поле chng, где, если получается первое ненулевое значение (COALESCE) из разницы максимальной даты date_position и максимальной даты date_position, уменьшенной на единицу.

Comment: Просмотрев весь код более внимательно, понял, в чём были ошибки, спасибо, что побудили перепроверить всё несколько раз повнимательнее)

Comment: Пожайлуста! Ну да, если бы прямо написал, что MAX (date_position) лишний, то было бы неинересно. Посмотрите в сторону [match_recognize](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+match_recognize), если есть желание решить более изящно.

Comment: Хорошо, обязательно изучу этот материал!